# Is there a way to implement a wildcard method with the function "find"?

Tags: python, string, design-patterns, find, wildcard

I'm very new to Python. I understand that the find function takes a string p and a substring s and returns the index at which s shows up in p. But if I had something like

```
p = 'abc'
text = 'aaaabbaac'
text.find(p)
```

Would it be possible to write a method that allows me to set the wildcard to b and still return the index at which a and c match, instead of returning -1?

I'm using this in a class that has two methods, the find method and a "setwildcard" method which takes a character and does what I described above. At default the wildcard is set to None.

Comment: No. Use regular expressions and `re.findall()`.

Comment: Asking how to "use regular expressions" is way too broad. Take a look at the documentation and try it out for yourself. The module is called `re` in Python, and is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You can [compile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) a regular expression pattern into a regular expression object, which can be used for matching using its `match()` and `search()` methods.

```
import re 
reObj2 = re.compile(pattern)  
reObj2.search(s)
```

> **re.match()** will only match at the beginning of the string and not at
>   the beginning of each line.
>
> **re.search()** scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance.

Also if you want to return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string,you can use `re.findall()`.

Have a look at [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents).

Hope this helps.